# Apache2 configuration, .htacces and 310 error (www redirection)

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an ubuntu apache serveur, with many websites.
all my website have the same bug ( so it's look like a misconfiguration)

http://www.2sigma.fr <- it's work fine ( we see "en travaux")

http://2sigma.fr <- dont work, i got 310 error (cyclic redirection!)

here my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}      ^2sigma\.fr$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)             http://www.2sigma.fr/$1      [R=301,L]
```

here my confguration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId sigma www-data
</IfModule>

    ServerAdmin monmail@gmail.com
    ServerName 2sigma.fr
    ServerAlias www.2sigma.fr
    DocumentRoot /home/sigma/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/sigma/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_sigma
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_sigma combined
    ServerSignature Off
```

If i use this .htaccess it's work fine :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}      ^2sigma\.fr$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)             http://www.google.fr/$1      [R=301,L]
```

I think that it is a apache configuration probleme... but i dont kno how to solve it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the help but it dont work. both http://2sigma.fr and http://www.2sigma.fr show the index.html without any rewriting

Comment: it's look like the rewritecond **%{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]** dont match..

Comment: Did you restart apache to ensure it took effect?

Comment: yes... but no effect.

Comment: Are you sure there's not other outside influences? You might want to (very briefly) enable debug output to your logs to track the rules being parsed.